# How to use Java AWT setBackground

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, colors, awt

This is some code to create a basic java window:

```
JPanel pane = new JPanel();
gui(String title){
    super(title);
    setBounds(100,100,500,500);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Container con = this.getContentPane();
*   con.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0));
    con.add(pane);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

The line marked with a star (*) is meant to make the window's background color black (0,0,0). However, that line seems to do nothing. (I have tried using `pane.setBackground` here, but that made no diffference.)

How do I change the background color?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have added the `JPanel` over the `JFrame` which completely blocks out the underlying container on which you have set the color.

You could do this instead:

```
public Gui(String title) {
   super(title);
   JPanel pane = new JPanel();
   setBounds(100, 100, 500, 500);
   setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   Container con = this.getContentPane();
   pane.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
   con.add(pane);
   setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: I tried adding that instead, and got no change. Where specfically should I put it?

Comment: It should go where the the asterisk * is.

Comment: That made no difference? Any clue why?

Comment: It works for me. I've posted the full constructor that I'm using.

Comment: Ah, a different part of the code was causing it to go white. Sorry about that.

Comment: Well, the existance of a `paint()` method seems to create a white layer over the screen, but the bit I asked the question about is working ok.

Comment: you cat to see ContentPane in the case JPanel#setOpaque()

Answer (score 1):

You can't set the background color for a JFrame's content pane.
By that I meant:

```
 JFrame f = new JFrame() ;
 f.setBackground(Color.RED) ;
```

What you should do however is create a JPanel that will act as your background and set its color like so:

`backgroundPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);`

Comment: I tried adding that, and got no difference. Where exactly should I put it?

Comment: Why can't you *set the background color for a `JFrame`'s content pane*?  `JFrame#setBackground` and `JFrame#getContentPane#setBackground` work just fine for me

Comment: Oops you are right. It was JFrame.setBackground(Color.RED) I will delete my answer when you've seen this comment.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Will do that:P

Answer (score 0):

```
Jframe f =new Jframe();
f.setBackground(Color.red);
```

This may also solve the Problem in hand.